Can a question begin with 'but'?
Extract from The Lottery Ticket by Anton Chekhov:

"I forgot to look at the newspaper today." said Masha, as she was clearing the table. "Is the list of lottery numbers in it?" "Yes, it is." said Ivan. "But you didn't buy a ticket this week ?"

My issue is: Should the final phrase have a question mark or a period at the end?
I am aware that there are two categories of interrogative sentences: yes/no questions and wh family questions, which start with what, why, who, etc. Which group does this question belong to?

Your post’s title and body formulate different questions. What is it that you wish to know? As to the title, a simple Google search will unearth quite a bit.

I saw the same sentence ending in a period and also question mark (when I searched the net). All the questions are related to the difference between the two. I felt asking in various ways could enable others to give a detailed answer.

I think this is a case where the difference between the two is far more interesting and shows how punctuation changes the meaning of the sentence. Changing it to a "can" question about grammar changes it to be a question about the expansiveness of "correct" grammar and loses the nuance of how punctuation influences meaning.

Should it have a question mark or a period at the end? That depends on if it was declarative or interrogative. - There are no words that you cannot start a sentence with.

Which group does this interrogative sentence belong to?

But you didn't buy a ticket this week [did you]? It's obviously a yes-no question.

But why male models?

See this question on questions without inversion. Rising intonation on a statement turns it into a question.

In Victorian times But could be used as a "discourse marker" at the start of a conversation (the way some people start their question on ELL today with So). In both cases the highlighted conjunction is always perfectly okay provided it refers back to something mentioned earlier in the conversation, regardless of whether the actual sentence it occurs in is a statement, question, exclamation, or whatever. I'm sure many Victorians objected to But as a conversation starter, just as many object to So being used like that today. The "question" aspect is irrelevant, though.

I think OP's two categories of interrogative sentences is not a useful perspective. The cited example is "non-standard" - not because it starts with But, but because it doesn't feature the standard subject-verb inversion: But didn't you buy a ticket this week? Probably that just (deliberately or otherwise) reflects the fact that the speaker isn't a native Anglophone. Apart from subject-verb inversion, the other defining feature of questions is rising intonation. With a written example we can't be sure that applies, but if we see a question mark it probably does.

But why would you want to start a question with "but"?

Of course you may agree that it is terrible style to start a question with "but". But if you disagree, which word would you start the question with but "but"?

In the original Russian, Masha had pawned off her lottery bond (not ticket). Ivan, a middle class man making 1200 rubles per year, thought that she had defaulted on the loan, but she reassured him that she had paid the interest on Tuesday. This brilliant description of the family money situation and their financial planning abilities in literally first four phrases of the story, unfortunately, seems to be lost in translation.

@Quassnoi The story is for an Indian audience, who would not understand what pawned off her lottery bond means.

@JamesMathai: I, of course, meant "pawned", not "pawned off". This translation was made by Constance Garnett in the early 1920s. What makes you think that it was intended for Indian audience?

The answer is a bit more complex than it may seem at first.  The question that is being asked is hidden in the context of the conversation.
To end the sentence with a period, would indicate that Ivan was reminding Masha that she did not buy a ticket.
To end the sentence with a question mark but without any context, would indicate that Ivan was asking an interrogative question, But you didn't buy a ticket this week [did you]?  The did you is implied by the presence of the question mark.
Within the context of the conversation, however, we learn that Masha is asking about the lottery numbers, while Ivan is aware that Masha did not buy a lottery ticket.  Ivan's question refers to this discrepancy between what Masha is asking and Masha's current situation.  Masha wants to know about lottery numbers even though she has not purchased a ticket.
When Ivan responds, Yes it is, he acknowledges that numbers are in the newspaper but his question then becomes, But you didn't buy a ticket [so why are you asking]?
It's a Wh question hidden in the context of a statement and indicated by a question mark.

In the story, Ivan is the husband and Masha, the wife. (Russian story)
Masha's reply, "Yes, I did. I bought a ticket on Thursday."

I did a little work on Masha.  She's all fixed up now.

Excellent analysis. Let's also add that it's a translation, that Chekhov wrote biting dramedies, and that "Yes, it is ... But" is virtually one sentence.

@Yosef: The analysis would have been excellent, had   JamesMathai not completely destroyed it because Masha did too, buy a ticket

@GwenKillerby Only Masha bought the ticket. It's not a suspense. The story revolves around this. The couple start imagining that they won the lottery.

Compare:

So, you want to buy my car?
-- Yes.
But you don't have any money and want to do a trade instead?
-- That's right.  I have a winning lottery ticket from 1954 that was never redeemed. It's probably worth millions and millions by now.

That kind of question, which has the form of a statement but is delivered (sometimes) with question intonation, is normally seeking confirmation of something that came up earlier in the conversation.
It means something like "I want to make sure my understanding of the situation is correct. Is it?"

I agree but it's always in conversation.

@Lambie There's a conversation going on between Masha and Ivan.

Yes, but I think you need to say it specifically as a reference for further usage. That's all.

It doesn't have to be in conversation. "We know he falsified the documents. But did he intend to influence the election?"

@Lambie    I think my statement is enough, that this form of question is "normally seeking confirmation of something that came up earlier in the conversation".  But it can be found where the "conversation" is no more than a convention,  as in an address to the reader that occurs in, say, a how-to book: "So, you want to buy a used car? But you're afraid of getting scammed? If so, you've come to the right place.  This book will tell you all you need to know to avoid being a patsy when buying a used car."
